# How to procede using Here Maps on a project that has multi application modules?

Tags: android, kotlin, module, here-api, credentials

So, my situation is the following:

- Android Application that already make use of Here Maps;
- This same app is now growing to be an app that has other apps within it, knowing that the first one will became a child;
- I just received rders to make the new child (module application) that it will use Here Maps too.

I'm uncertain about to procede right now, will be necessary (App_Id, App_Code, and licenseKey) for each one of the childs that will use it or can I reuse the credentials of the first one?

Hope it is clear to everyone. I'm open to try to clarify if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credentials are not tied to the package name or the application id of your app, but to the account used to obtain the credentials. This makes it possible to use the same set of credentials for multiple apps.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.here.sdk.access_key_id" android:value="YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID" />
<meta-data android:name="com.here.sdk.access_key_secret" android:value="YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET" />
```

Comment: Thank very much, i finally could try using the same credentials in another module and it worked fine.